# Java script issue with WPF WebBrowser control as IE browser not supported

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I am using .NET WPF WebBrowser control in our application and for particular site say "**https://www.accuweather.com/**" it throwing a java script error. and if you click on it say yes than it open partial site stating as "**Your version of Internet Explorer is no longer supported. Please upgrade your browser for the best AccuWeather experience".**

Though I have IE 11 installed on my machine and above URL works fine along with it if I open it in directly IE web browser.

So I am looking for a generic solution so that I can suppress this java script error or can show web page without this. As our client is not happy with this java script pop-up.

Also I don't want to use Winform WebBrowser control in my WPF application neither I want this windows registry to be changed as I don't know my various application users IE version.

So need some generic solution for the same.

Please reply with fix or generic solution guys!

Thanks!
Vinod Bhatt